# How do you upgrade TigerGraph?

Tags: database, nosql, tigergraph

Right now we have TigerGraph 2.1.0 and we want to install the newest version 2.1.4. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Prerequisites:**

1. Currently only upgrading within the same minor version is supported (i.e. 2.1.x -> 2.1.y)

*To upgrade to a different minor version (i.e. 2.1.x -> 2.2.y), you might need to contact support@tigergraph.com.*

**Upgrade Within the Same Minor Version:**

1. Login as the tigergraph user. (For cluster configurations please login to node m1)
2. Download the tigergraph tarball for the version you want to upgrade to (i.e. tigergraph-2.1.8-offline.tar.gz).
3. Untar the offline tarball and install tigergraph.bin with the following commands:

```
tar -xzf tigergraph-x.y.z-offline.tar.gz #replace x.y.z with the version you downloaded in the previous step
cd tigergraph-x.y.z-offline
bash tigergraph.bin -v

#i.e. for 2.1.8:
#tar -xzf tigergraph-2.1.8-offline.tar.gz
#cd tigergraph-2.1.8-offline
#bash tigergraph.bin -v
```